# Rabbitmq queue sharding

Tags: rabbitmq, sharding

I have to implement this scenario:
An external application publish message to rabbitmq. 
This message has a client_id property. We can place this id to routing key or message header or some other property.
I have to implement sharding in a exchange routng logic - the message should be delivered to specific queue based on the client_id range.

Is it possible to implement in a standard exchanges?
If not what exchange should I take as the base?
How to dynamicly change client_id ranges?

Comment: Did you find a solution? i need the same basically

Comment: No. We had to implement this functionality outside of rabbitmq.

Comment: Actually i've managed to solve it using consistent hash exchange (as i don't care about ranges, i care about distribution) and weights - i believe that for ranges - you can go with x-modulus-hash exchange.
whenever we need "new" shard, we create a new subscriber and queue, and bind it to that same exchange. thus, each subscriber will naturally handle only part of the data.
if it gets unrelated data (because of added shards) - we can just resend the msg to the exchange and it will route it to the correct q.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [rabbitmq plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding). It's included in the RabbitMQ distribution from v3.6.0 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Just have your producer put enough info into the routing key that causes the message to go into the right queue on the other side of the Exchange.

So for example, create two queues called 1 and 2 and bind them with routing keys matching the names. Then have your producer decide which routing key to use when producing the event message. Customers with names starting with letters a-m go to 1, n-z go to 2, you get the idea. It pushes the sharding to the producer but that might be OK for your application.

Comment: It's not ideal solution because  external application should not know internal logic.

Comment: They you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Not only that, but it would be very useful to be able to add and remove additional queues without changing the publisher.

Answer (score 0):

AMQP doesn't have any explicit implementation of sharding, but its architecture should help you to do that.

Spreading messages to several queues is just a rabbitmq challenge (and part of amqp specification), and with routing, way you can attach hetereogeneous consumers to handle specific messages routed via the same exchange. Therefore, producer should push a specific key to be consumed by specific queue/consumer...

You can decide to make a static sharding, perhaps you have 10 queues with one consumer per queue. You could implement a consistent hashing function such that key is CLIENT_ID % 10.

Another ways and none static solutions could be propoused, and you can try to  over this architecture.